# How to count value from substring

Tags: mysql

I have some trouble when make count from sparated value,
here is my query

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.therapi, ',', n.n), ',', -1) value
FROM tbl_riwayat t CROSS JOIN 
(
  SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n FROM 
  (
    SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
    ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n
  ) n
  WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.therapi) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.therapi, ',', '')))
  ORDER BY value
```

And here is result

```
value
---------------
|Nodrop|
|Nodrop|
|Test1|
|Test2|
```

I want to count value like `Nodrop = 2` `Test1 = 1` `Test2 = 1`

Comment: simple use `group by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT t1.value, COUNT(t1.value) FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.therapi, ',', n.n), ',', -1) value
FROM tbl_riwayat t CROSS JOIN 
(
  SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n FROM 
  (
    SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
    ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n
  ) n
  WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.therapi) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.therapi, ',', '')))
  ORDER BY value) t1 GROUP BY t1.value
```

Comment: you can just remove t1.value from the first select statement

Comment: ohh, sorry I not focuss, I already confusing now, but thanks you helped me,, thanks a lot